# Java watchService creating strange events

Tags: java, windows-7, java-8, watchservice

I'm using Java `WatchService`to watch for changes in a local directory. 
I'm seeing some weird events created when testing on win 7 which I don't understand how to manage.

If I paste a new folder into the watched directory I get: `ENTRY_CREATE` , `ENTRY_MODIFY`, I can easily ignore the modify by checking the modified date

...however...

if I save a new file directly into the watched directory I'm getting: `ENTRY_CREATE`, `ENTRY_DELETE`, `ENTRY_CREATE`, `ENTRY_MODIFY`
 I can't seem to figure out why it's putting in the extra delete & create events.

Anyone able to shed some light on why this is happening and/or how to manage it?

(NOTE: the entry_modify event has count of 2, however the all the create/delete ones have count of 1)

Comment: What program are you using to save the new file? Some programs create temporary files that may be deleted when no longer needed. Is there any way to get the filenames associated with `ENTRY_CREATE`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm using notepad. Printing out the event context on each event I get the same file name _tester.txt_

Comment: Best I've got at the moment is to check when I get a 'delete' event, how long it's been since the file was edited. If it's under 4 sec, I ignore it. works, but not ideal...

Comment: maybe it's just what notepad does. try tracing it with the sysinternals [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)

Comment: I verified with Process Monitor and it is indeed what Notepad (and others) do; the file is created and deleted again in the process… Since the watch service only reports what is really happening, there is no way around it, other than deferring any reaction to the events, though 4 secs look too much to me. I usually get them all together in a single `pollEvents` call…